# Start browser session from within another website

Tags: javascript, ajax, rest, cross-domain, session-cookies

***Context***

1. Users work on website A (SPA, Angular)
2. To get more info about specific entities they can be redirected to website B (website B is open in a new tab)
3. Both websites belong to different companies but there is a contract so that users of page A have access to page B
4. There is a redirect https://websiteA/redirect... that does a redirect to https://websiteB/... so that the user has an active session on websiteB

***Problem / Question / Requirement***

We would like to be informed on websiteA that the session on websiteB has been established, what possibilities do we have?!

**Possibility A) Open websiteB in new tab**

If we open the session-building redirect in a new tab it works and the cookies with session data are saved in the browser for websiteB. So the following requests to websiteB work, the user is logged in. Only problem, we have no info about those tabs in the js of websiteA and don't know if it worked.

window.open returns null. No chance to get for example an onLoad event of websiteB. **Are there any headers the server of websiteB can set for websiteA to be able to get info about a success?**

**Possibility B) Ajax Request (Angular HttpClient)**
If I do the session-building request with ajax, will that save cookies? A first test with a nodejs server shows me, that the httpClient follows the redirect to websiteB but when I open a tab on websiteB afterwards I see no saved cookies. **Are there any headers the server of websiteB can set so that cookies are also set when it's an ajax request?**

Any other possibilities you see how website A can know if the session has been established?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OAuth

Comment: OAuth or some SSO tech. would for sure work. But as we don't need to access any resource of website B except for a flag if the page has been loaded successfully, this also seem like overkill.
It's sufficient for us to just time two request to website B: load page2 after page1 has been loaded successfully. In addition page1 needs to have the chance to save cookies...but we don't need access to them. We need no access to any website B resources.